What services allow you to send emails?
I'm doing my PET project.
I set myself the following task: I need to implement password reset functionality.
My idea is that in order to reset your password, you should first receive a confirmation link by email.
And this is where I ran into a problem.
I use Node => nodemailer.
Google is a lot of work, and most other SMTP services require a domain, which I don't have.
The question is, can you recommend me an SMTP service that can add an email to an email, that is free and doesn't require a domain.

I have used Sendgrid and Twilio, both have a free tier for hobby / testing, at least last I checked, and neither requires a domain (you do need to specify a return address of course).
For both, you make an API call to their service and it sends an email. I used Twilio to test a Proof of Concept app I built when I was at Blue Cross.
Good luck!
